# Atomicity of C# Coalescing Operator

Tags: c#, atomic, null-coalescing-operator

I ran into some singleton code today in our codebase and I wasn't sure if the following was thread-safe:

```
public static IContentStructure Sentence{ 
    get {
       return _sentence ?? (_sentence = new Sentence()); 
    }
}
```

This statement is equivalent to:

```
if (_sentence != null) {
       return _sentence;
}
else {
    return (_sentence = new Sentence());
}
```

I believe that ?? is just a compiler trick and that the resulting code is still NOT atomic. In other words, two or more threads could find _sentence to be null before setting _sentence to a new Sentence and returning it.

To guarantee atomicity, we'd have to lock that bit of code:

```
public static IContentStructure Sentence{ 
    get {

       lock (_sentence) { return _sentence ?? (_sentence = new Sentence()); }
    }
}
```

Is that all correct?

Comment: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: Except that you can't lock on something that is null, so your solution will never work.

Comment: good point.  Yea you'd have to create another object to lock on. Good catch.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are correct; it's not at all thread-safe.

Answer (score 16):

> I ran into some singleton code today in our codebase

Do you have such obfuscated code throughout your codebase?  This code does the same thing:

```
if (_s == null) 
    _s = new S();
return _s;
```

and is about a thousand times easier to read.

> I believe that ?? is just a compiler trick and that the resulting code is still NOT atomic

You are correct. C# makes the following guarantees of atomicity:

> Reads and writes of the following data types are atomic: bool, char, byte, sbyte, short, ushort, uint, int, float, and reference types. In addition, reads and writes of enum types with an underlying type in the previous list are also atomic. Reads and writes of other types, including long, ulong, double, and decimal, as well as user-defined types, are not guaranteed to be atomic. Aside from the library functions designed for that purpose, there is no guarantee of atomic read-modify-write, such as in the case of increment or decrement.

The null coalescing operator is not on that list of guarantees.

> To guarantee atomicity, we'd have to lock that bit of code:

```
lock (_sentence) { return _sentence ?? (_sentence = new Sentence()); } } }
```

Good heavens no. That crashes immediately!

The correct thing to do is one of:

- Stop trying to write multithreaded code.
- Write a singleton using one of the safe singleton patterns Jon Skeet documents on his page about singletons.
- Use the `Lazy<T>` class.
- Lock on an object dedicated to locking that variable.
- Use an Interlocked Compare Exchange to do an atomic test and set.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Interlocked.CompareExchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h7etff8w.aspx) with `null` to get a `??`-esque operation that is atomic.

```
// I made up my own Sentence type
Sentence current = null;
var whenNull = new Sentence() {Text = "Hello World!"};

var original = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref current, new Sentence() { Text = "Hello World!" }, null);

Assert.AreEqual(whenNull.Text, current.Text);
Assert.IsNull(orig);

// try that it won't override when not null
current.Text += "!";
orig = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref current, new Sentence() { Text = "Hello World!" }, null);

Assert.AreEqual("Hello World!!", current.Text);
Assert.IsNotNull(orig);
```

Comment: Downside of that is that you create a new `Sentence` for each pass through, no?

Comment: @DrewNoakes: You are correct. It is more idiomatic to do the compare exchange only if the current is null. Then the only time you create the object twice is in the unlikely race. If it is unacceptable to ever create the object twice then there are other techniques you can use.

Comment: So, you should be able to do the following: var x = current ?? Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref current, new Sentence(), null) ?? current;